# Issues in installing node-js latest version on squeeze

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, g++, debian

I was developing an app with node-js. I was trying to install  node-js on one of squeeze debian linux machine.

The issue I was facing, while compiling node code, it needs g++ version >= 4.9, but squeeze has only g++ versions till 4.4.5.

Please let me know how to circumvent this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in [this link](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2015/01/13/raspberry-pi-raspbian-install-gcc-compile-cpp-14-programs/), can/did you try

```
sudo apt-get update
  //and install GCC 4.9
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9 g++-4.9
```

---

Edited by Saurabh:

So the solution was to get sources of `jessie`, by replacing `jessie` with `wheezy`in file: `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: Yes, I get following error: `E: Unable to locate package gcc-4.9
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'gcc-4.9'
E: Unable to locate package g++-4.9
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'g++-4.9'` 
Because these packages are not available for squeeze.

Comment: Did you change squeeze  with jessie in  /etc/apt/sources.list before running the apt-get update? If not try that once. I faced a similar issue on debian wheezy and following the steps in the post helped. Hope it would fix your issue too.
Note: don't forget to revert back the changes in sources.list after update.